# Substituting SQL double pipe In Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I would like to remove the SQL in crystal reports and filter it with the equivalent logic in the select expert tool to make the migration from a older version to a newer version easier.

The issues that I've run into is a SQL query like the following

```
WHERE YEAR||MONTH >= '201504'
AND WHERE YEAR||MONTH <='201602'
```

Intuitively this makes sense, a query where between April 2015 and February 2016.

I don't see how this is possible in the Select Expert tool as I can indicate the year and month and values they can be between, but not specify a range like the one indicated above.

Essentially if its possible to rewrite this statement using the basic operators ('<' '<=' '=') for my year and month, that would solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{table.year}&{table.month} in ("201504" to "201602")
```

or if your fields are numbers

```
totext({table.year},"#")&totext({table.month},"#") in ("201504" to "201602")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Perfect solution for what I was looking for.